# Label Street Names on Layout at City Level

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, layouts, pdf

Just wanted to rephrase my question.

What I'd like is to have all labels for cross-streets that meet at an intersection in a city visible when I export a layout from ArcMap. Really all I need is the text to be legible when a user zooms into the exported PDF.

So the 2 problems I'm facing then are:

1. Selecting only those streets that meet at an intersection for labelling.
2. Labelling them so that they don't overlap etc. and are legible.

Comment: So you want to include GIS functionality in a PDF? To my knowledge PDF's are static (ok, you can turn on/off layers and stuff like that, but not dynamically changing labels depending on the scale)

Comment: Ditto what MrXsquared said. You might just have to do your best with Maplex Label Engine.